# Unable to install Mongodb on my ubuntu18.04.02 LTS

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-18.04

```
yca@yca-laptop:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install mongodb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb : Depends: mongodb-server (>= 1:2.4.1-2) but it is not going to be installed
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed
               Conflicts: mongodb but 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
 mongodb-org-shell : Conflicts: mongodb but 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
N: Ignoring file 'mongodb-org-3.6.listsudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

i try to install mongo db via command line.but mogodb cannot able to install beacause of following error.

Comment: You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.

Answer (score 1):

It's more of an askubuntu case, but here are few things you can try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

apt --fix-broken install

sudo apt-get install mongodb-server mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-tools
```

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not installed